# Trouble with queryparams in iframe

Tags: ember.js

I am having some trouble with queryParams. My application is loaded into an iframe were I need to grab some values off of the url that is called. I have no control over how the url is formatted.

The url looks like this:

blah.com/something/index.html?param1=blah

Playing around on jsbin i noticed that the below url works.

blah.com/something/index.html/#/?param1=blah

Is there a way to configure the params to work with the url I am provided by the app that loads in my page?

jsbin - http://jsbin.com/migiqe

Comment: Have a look at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html.

Comment: I tried setting the location to history before and I blew up the app.  I totally spaced on the rootURL option for the router.  Thank you for help.

http://jsbin.com/migiqe/7/